# Note of greetingth

Tags: word, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, cipher, cryptic-clues

A friend of mine thent me thith note. He'th a little bit thy and often preferth to thend a metthage rather than thay thomething in perthon, even if it'th quite thort, and thometimeth amutheth himthelf by putting it in the form of a putthle. I honethtly have no idea what to make of thith one though, although from what he thaid when he gave it to me, I think one of the lineth on the left ith encrypted quite thimply, uthing a different technique to the otherth. I've pothted it here, in cathe any of the brilliant putthlerth on thith thite can help me with it. What ith he trying to thay?

---

[image: Note]

---

**Edit**: Sincere apologies, there was a slight error in the original image. I've updated the image. It will not change the solution; there was a word misspelled at one point - you could certainly solve the puzzle using the original image, and if anyone is partway through the solution, they should be able easily to modify it. The corrected text can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/7dzUvfFY).

---

**Hint**: I'm not sure whether anyone's working on this, and if so where they're stuck, so I'll begin with a basic hint in case anyone wants to give it a crack...

> Spoiler alert: The first line on the left should be trivial to decode (practically at sight) for anyone who's spent time on this site.
>
> The *answer* to that first line on the left is a word that should also be very familiar to most regular users of this site.

Feel free to post partial answers, as there's a few little steps to this puzzle.

---

**Hint 2**: Since there was some interest in this puzzle, but there's been no progress in about a month, I thought I'd post a little hint in case anyone is still interested...

> @Stiv and @LukasRotter have made significant progress here. They have found solutions to the first four lines which read:
>
> VIGENERE FOU
> PASCAL GMO
> SAINT CDJ
> CENDRARS JPQ
> GISBERT ???
>
> @Stiv has also discovered the historical figures to whom each line refers. The obvious next task then is to discover the source of the three letter combinations (FOU, GMO, CDJ, JPQ), so that the ??? triplet can be deduced. The presentation of the puzzle might be useful here...
>
> Another task that can be worked on separately is to find how the rightmost triplets (TAM, LBT, VSV, IBQ, KSJ) fit into the rest of the puzzle, so that the boxed triplet ??? can be deduced.

Comment: Does your friend happen to have a lisp xD

Comment: @WilliamPennanti A possible conclusion haha

Comment: @Anon Shouldn't the "metthage" be spelled as "meththage"?

Comment: Mutht anthwers to thith quethtion be pothted entirely in the thame lithping thtyle?

Comment: @defectedWBC Haha I had to pick a way to spell it. Don't get hung up on details in the background text. Essentially everything you need to solve the puzzle is in the image. (Although the lithp ith obviouthly there for a reathon).

Comment: @Randal'Thor I'll let you pathh on that one, but maybe you'll get ekthtra pointth if you do (no promithe on that one though).

Comment: Sincere apologies, there was a slight error in the original image. I've updated the image; it will not change the solution, there was just a word misspelled - you could certainly solve the puzzle using the original image, and if anyone is partway through the solution, they should be able easily to modify it. The corrected text can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/7dzUvfFY)

Comment: I've expanded the hint. I've kept it as one hint, since I've added almost no new information, just clarified exactly what the first hint means, in case anyone is wanting to give the puzzle a crack.

Comment: Another of my puzzles had some increased interest, and looking over my unsolved puzzles I realized how close to a solution this one had come, so I couldn't resist summarizing the progress so far and posting a hint.

Answer (score 12):

<sub>*A partial answer but with excellent progress, thanks in part to insights from @LukasRotter*</sub>

---

**Line 1:**

```
ANRIVPBAPYHQVATVANHTHENGVBATRAHSYRPGORSBERZRNAFGBPBAPRNYJBEQF
```

This line of text is encoded using:

> [rot-13](https://rot13.com/)

and decodes as:

> NAEVICONCLUDINGINAUGURATIONGENUFLECTBEFOREMEANSTOCONCEALWORDS. Adding spaces in sensible places produces:
>  **NAEVI CONCLUDING INAUGURATION GENUFLECT BEFORE MEANS TO CONCEAL WORDS**

What is this? Well, it's...

> a cryptic clue of sorts. Specifically, if we take the last ('*concluding*') letters of NAE**VI** and the starting ('*inauguration*') letters of **GEN**UFLECT, then add the word **ERE**, which in poetry means '*before*', then we produce something which is a '*means to conceal words*' - i.e. it points towards the **VIGENÈRE** cipher.

**Line 2:**

```
BZGRQTRWHOFXCREGMFRMWXKZKWFYIIVIUIBOJVII [KRC]
```

This line of the puzzle is encoded using the cipher indicated by decoding line 1, so now we need to identify a key. In my first answer posting I initially posted some findings of my early attempts to find such a thing. One of my observations enabled @LukasRotter to make a breakthrough in comments (reproduced here with thanks):

> Initially I found that if we attempt to decode this using the key 'VIGENERE' we produce the 'plaintext' GRANDPASMGZTPNNCRXLIJTTVPOZUVEEEZAVKWRRE, which appears to begin with the real word *GRANDPAS*, suggesting we may be on to something. Lukas then noticed that if we also included the triplet 'SBH' at the end of line 1 before decoding with rot-13, this resulted in the triplet 'FOU'. If we attach *this* to the end of our key and decode line 2 using the key 'VIGENEREFOU' we *do* produce some output in the form of a series of English words, which once spaces are added spells out:
>  **GRANDPAS CALCULATION HID PRESSURE QUANTIFIER [GMO]**

What is this? Well, it's...

> another cryptic clue, which results in the answer **PASCAL**, since 'GRAND**PAS CAL**CULATION' hides the letter sequence 'PASCAL', which is the name of a scientific unit of *pressure*. This suggests that the key for the next line will be 'PASCALGMO', where GMO is the decoding of the 'KRC' triplet.

**Line 3:**

```
QEDKEGKDVTAJFEDYMMXNLJEMKSWCNAPG [NJV]
```

This decodes as follows:

> It's another Vigenere cipher, this time requiring the key 'PASCALGMO' as found above. The resulting plaintext is:
>  **BELIEVER HEARD ESSAY IN THE BEGINNING [CDJ]**

What is this? Yep, you guessed it! It's...

> another cryptic clue! The definition is BELIEVER. 'HEARD ESSAY' gives **S A** ('ess ay' when read aloud, i.e. 'heard'), which needs to be followed by **IN** and **T** (being the *beginning* of 'THE'). The answer is thus **SAINT** and our keyword for the next line is 'SAINTCDJ'...

**Line 4:**

```
FEEJHTGXXPWRMUZRDLBETPVLWNLEXILBLRIELGQMANOF [CRT]
```

This decodes in similar fashion:

> It's another Vigenere cipher, using key 'SAINTCDJ' and reveals the plaintext:
>  **NEW WORD OF POETS WILL TRANSCEND REGISTRARS ENDINGS [JPQ]**

By now, you should recognise what you're looking at here...

> Another cryptic clue, of course. A bit of an obscure one, but @LukasRotter spotted in comments that this could result in the answer **CENDRARS**, referring to the surname adopted by the poet [Blaise Cendrars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaise_Cendrars). (Obtain this from the *endings* of TRANS**CEND** REGIST**RARS**...) Couple this with 'JPQ' to gain the key 'CENDRARSJPQ' for the final line...

**Line 5:**

```
CRBWVIJJNIKTRVQXUEWWSYPKULXHGACRXGHADDEDWJCYPKILMIUNXL [???]
```

Decode this line as per the others...

> (Vigenere cipher, this time using the keyword 'CENDRARSJPQ'), yielding the plaintext:
>  **A NOTE IS RETURNING UNENDING HIGH PITCHED NAME MEANING VIVID VOW**

And again, this is...

> a cryptic clue, which results in the answer **GISBERT**, which is a *name* meaning '[bright pledge](https://anesthesiologie.umontreal.ca/recherche/chercheurs/gilbert-blaise/)', a synonym of '*vivid vow*'. Here, 'A (musical) NOTE' is **G**, then we have **IS** and 'HIGH PITCHED' is 'TREBLE' - if this word were *unending* it would be 'TREB', then *returning* (reversing) it gives us **BERT**.

**Next steps:**

The first thing to notice is doubtless that there is a connection between all the keywords we have discovered so far (even mentioned at one point!). Each of our keywords...

> can be paired with **BLAISE** to make the name of a famous person:
>
>  [Blaise de VIGENÈRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaise_de_Vigen%C3%A8re)
>  [Blaise PASCAL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaise_Pascal)
>  [SAINT Blaise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Blaise)
>  [Blaise CENDRARS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaise_Cendrars)
>  [Blaise GISBERT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaise_Gisbert)

So what do we with this knowledge? A couple of thoughts:

> - Possibly we are supposed to use 'BLA' and 'ISE' to complete the two sets of question marks at the bottom of the puzzle...
>
>  - Possibly the lisp comes into it here and the letters 'BLAITHE' (substituting the 'S' with 'TH') becomes important...
>
>  - And we also have to deal with the presentation of the piece, notably the cross at the top of the puzzle...

*A little more thought required, but possibly almost there...*

Comment: LOL who keeps downvoting these partial answers? It may not be worth a full upvote to everybody, but a downvote? The answer is useful...

Comment: @LukasRotter Thanks - you're right, there have been a lot of answers downvoted lately without justification. All very odd :) We were even encouraged by the OP on this puzzle to post partials - which is very common for this puzzle type because with serial ciphers it's often very hard to make progress through more than one step at a time. Anyway, hopefully it might actually get the ball rolling and help someone to spot the next key...

Comment: I figured out the next step. But I'm so horrible at cryptic clues that there's no point to continue trying :) So there you go: rot13(EBG13 gur grkg arkg gb gur svefg yvar, "FOU" -> lbh trg "SBH". Nccraq gung gb gur xrl, fb "IVTRARERSBH", qrpelcg ntnva, lbh trg nabgure pelcgvp pyhr: "TENAQCNF PNYPHYNGVBA UVQ CERFFHER DHNAGVSVRE")

Comment: @LukasRotter Nice work :) I think I can see what it means too... Will add it in with credit, thanks.

Comment: Next key is rot13(praqenef[wcd]) yielding rot13(N ABGR VF ERGHEAVAT HARAQVAT UVTU CVGPU RQ ANZR ZRNAVAT IVIVQ IBJ)

Comment: @LukasRotter Ah nice! I had half of that from brute-forcing it backwards but couldn't suss the rest as it didn't seem like a real word... No wonder! Thanks :)

Comment: @LukasRotter Stiv I'm so happy this puzzle is finally getting solved! I was always sad it hadn't been attempted yet. (These were the first cryptic clues I wrote, so I apologize for their quality). You just need two more insights to get to the heart of this puzzle, both of which can be realized by noting that nothing is irrelevant in the puzzle's presentation... One (fairly obvious?) insight into what links the lines of the puzzle should reveal the problem with your last hypothesis in 'Next Steps'.

Comment: @Anon As luck would have it I'd just solved a cryptic clues puzzle and that gave me the insights for this one! Your clues aren't bad at all for a first attempt - some of the definitions are a tad obscure but the wordplays work really well! Will keep thinking on the next step - needs a little playabout :)

Comment: @Stiv I almost missed it at first reading through your answer, but your interpretation of the final cryptic clue is off by a tiny amount. There's a word in the wordplay that you've missed in your interpretation... That will give you a more famous person (your choice of person seems a bit out of place among the others...)

Comment: @Anon Yeah, I did think that one was a bit off - now corrected, thanks! :)